# Deconvolution vs tf.Reshape

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, autoencoders, transposed-convolution, deconvolution

I currently have a 1D-CNN which produces a 1D output due to the dense layers at the end of said CNN but want it to produce a 2D output. Instead of reshaping my tensor elements using tf.reshape, would I be able to use the tf.keras.layers.Conv1DTranspose deconvolution layer as a means of reshaping instead?

This makes the network structure synonymous with an autoencoder but I am seeking to use the network to make optimal decisions rather than replicating the input. Are there notable papers that have done this or reasons to not use deconvolution as a means of reshaping?

Thanks.